# Cannot find module `prettier' in VSCode with Yarn PnP (Extensions do not work with YARN PnP)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, yarnpkg, prettier

Since upgrading to Yarn 2+ (Berry), and later Yarn 4 with PnP support, VSCode cannot resolve locations for extensions prettier, eslint and others. In VSCode I receive the following error message:

`Error: Cannot find module 'prettier'`

I've ensured prettier is installed correctly, updated every prettier config possible, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you installed `ZipFS` extension and run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`?

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR: `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

VSCode couldn't resolve prettier inside of `node_modules` since that folder doesn't exist when PnP is enabled. The fix was super easy, as described in [Yarn's documentation on Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks).

### From Yarn Docs: [Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks)

"Smart IDEs (such as VSCode or IntelliJ) require special configuration for TypeScript to work when using Plug'n'Play installs."

This script installed and configured a bunch of files in my `.yarn` directory, and immediately solved my issues. Check out the links above to read more.

Comment: Ideally this solution would have been shared in the closely related https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1502 thread but it's locked, unfortunately. Hopes this helps some folks.